# Reading/Writing 32 bit 32bit DateTime to/from byte array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read and write a 32 bit datetime value from a byte array. I managed to find the 64 bit version. Does anyone know an easy way to do this but with a 32bit date/time?

```
//Go from byte array to Time/Date
long utcNowLongBack = BitConverter.ToInt64(utcNowBytes, 0);
DateTime utcNowBack = DateTime.FromBinary(utcNowLongBack);

//Create 32 bit byte array from Time/Date
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
long utcNowAsLong = utcNow.ToBinary();
byte[] utcNowBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(utcNowAsLong);
```

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkf9tah.aspx

Comment: You have to use two 32 Bit values to represent one long value.

Comment: The project im working on requires that the date is 2 bytes, the time is 2 bytes

Comment: You'll need to encode it yourself in that format, as the built in DateTime stuff encodes to 64bits as you've seen.  Presumably you're going to lose some level of accuracy by doing so.

Comment: You have to tell us what those bytes mean, I think. For the 64 bit example you posted, it's a timestamp. But if you have 2 bytes date and 2 bytes time it must be structured som other way.

Comment: @ChristopherVickers It must be using custom date/time encoding. 2 bytes for the date only gives a maximum range of approximately 180 years. 2 bytes for the time gives less than one-second accuracy, since there are more than 2^16 seconds in a day. What is the encoding used?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. I have to change some time values inside of a zip file so I am stuck with a 32bit date/time. I was trying to avoid do all the encoding. Hopefully there is an easy solution

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkf9tah.aspx

Comment: You cannot do this without knowing how the date/time is encoded into two 16-bit values. There are many different possibilities.

Comment: Ah so you're saying that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkf9tah.aspx) is the 32-bit format.

Comment: @ChristopherVickers If you want easy solutions, programming isn't the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly tricky to do the bitmasking and juggling yourself, but if you want to just "use something ready-made", I think the simplest thing is to call out to native code.

Read the two components into two `UInt16`, and call [`DosDateTimeToFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724247(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int DosDateTimeToFileTime(ushort dateValue, ushort timeValue, out UInt64 fileTime);

public static DateTime FromDosDateTime(ushort date, ushort time)
{
    UInt64 fileTime;
    if(DosDateTimeToFileTime(date, time, out fileTime) == 0) {
        throw new Exception($"Date conversion failed: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
    }

    return DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(fileTime));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct to convert to/from the 16 + 16 bits Date/Time... Clearly using bitwise operations! :-)

```
public struct DosDateTime
{
    public ushort Date;
    public ushort Time;

    public int Year
    {
        get => ((Date >> 9) & 0x7F) + 1980;
        set => Date = (ushort)((Date & 0x1FF) | ((value - 1980) << 9));
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get => (Date >> 5) & 0xF;
        set => Date = (ushort)((Date & 0xFE1F) | (value<< 5));
    }

    public int Day
    {
        get => Date & 0x1F;
        set => Date = (ushort)((Date & 0xFFE0) | value);
    }

    public int Hour
    {
        get => (Time >> 11) & 0x1F;
        set => Time = (ushort)((Time & 0x7FF) | (value << 11));
    }

    public int Minute
    {
        get => (Time >> 5) & 0x3F;
        set => Time = (ushort)((Time & 0xF81F) | (value << 5));
    }

    public int Second
    {
        get => (Time & 0x1F) << 1;
        set => Time = (ushort)((Time & 0xFFE0) | (value >> 1));
    }
}
```

The two `ushort` `Date` and `Time` are in the "format" used by the Dos FAT Date Time structures (because that is the format that is used, the one of the old FAT file system). The various properties are "backed" by the two `Date`/`Time` fields and make the correct bitwise calculations.

Comment: I think the second field will be wrong? Seconds in DOS time are stored with a granularity of 2, not 1.

Comment: @gnud Take a better look in the `Second` property. There is a `<< 1` (that is a `* 2`) and a `>> 1` (that is a `/ 2`)

Comment: You're right, sorry. I think I read the minute property, because I would have noticed the shift.