# FatFs date and time to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, fatfs

I'm trying to convert UInt16 values representing FatFs date and time ([here](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/sfileinfo.html)) into C# DateTime object. I have two UInt16 values representing fdate and ftime as seen in the link.

Whats the easiest way to convert those into a DateTime in C#?

Comment: `((fdate & 0b_1111111_0000_00000) >> 9) + 1980` would give you the year. The other fields would be extracted analogously.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640331/reading-writing-32-bit-32bit-datetime-to-from-byte-array